# node.js server with unused port

Tags: node.js, httpserver

I need to write a script that starts a `node.js` server on an unused port, and then interacts with that server. In order to do so, the script must know the port that was chosen.

In the JS code, I wanted to use something like `server.listen(0)` to let the OS pick the port, and then use `server.address().port` to retrieve the value. However, I am not sure how I could programmatically send that port back to the caller script. I can't use the return value, because it would kill the server.

Else, I could try to find a port in the script (this would be rather messy, as it needs to be portable) and attempt to call the `node.js` code with that fixed port, repeating with a new port until it works. Not great.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: you could do various ways, like use a shared EventEmitter https://nodejs.org/api/events.html, also could use worker_threads https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html or even the stdout from a child_process which you parse, also you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-port and assign the port before starting the server

Comment: The issue is that the caller script is not some JS code, but some sort of shell. I can run something like `node startAServerAndSomehowGiveMeBackItsPort.js` and do basic things but that's about it.